# How to unlimit 60 FPS in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I use setAnimationInterver() function to set my game fps 6000 (because of test).

ex:) Director::sharedDirector()->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 6000);

But.. there is no change in FPS. Max FPS is steel limited in 60.
How to unlimit 60 FPS in cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS is restricted to 1/60 limit due to the use of [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacescnscene/1650883-preferredframespersecond). I believe the other platforms may also use restrictive options when creating their OpenGL view that prevents > 60fps due to use of vsync, for example.

There are definitely ways to disable this if you prefer on each platform where supported.

Update 2017-06-16: "Pro Motion" displays will have the capability to both use more fps intervals as well as possibly adaptable fps that changes over time.